# Ruby SFTP issue

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-sftp

I am brand new to Ruby programming.  Shortly after completing some free online lessons, I decided I wanted to complete a real world practical script.

I want to automate some file transfers using the SFTP protocol.  I have installed the required gems (net-ssh, and net-sftp). But it appears I cannot connect to the server I am developing against. I am only trying to connect to the server with my script.  I am not performing any SFTP commands.  I have the following code:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ssh'
    require 'net/sftp'

    Net::SFTP.start('server_ip_address','username', password => 'password') do |sftp|
        puts "Connected!"
    end
```

I keep getting the following error:

**C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.3.beta1/lib/net/ssh/transport/ses
sion.rb:71:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
ailed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) for "(server_name)" port 22 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)**

I am able to connect to the SFTP server using FileZilla from my machine.  I am developing from a Windows 7 64bit laptop, Ruby 2.2.0 installed.

Does anybody have any ideas on why I cannot connect to the remote server?

This is also my very first question on StackOverflow.  If I did not list enough information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have your customized your SSH port, maybe not 22? Or, you may check your SSH log on your server first. My CentOS server's default SSH log is at `/var/log/secure`, yours may be customized in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Thank you for the input @ifyouseewendy.  I hadn't really considered the configuration on the remote server. It turns out I was trying to SFTP to a Windows server running FreeFTPd.  I was unable to SSH to that server via a Putty session, so that does explain why my code cannot connect.  I did switch my connection parameters to a Linux SFTP server and my code works!  So I guess my next question is, would there be any way in Ruby to connect to a Windows box running SFTP hosting software?  Perhaps this should be its own question?

Comment: Haven't experienced connecting to a Windows SFTP, and maybe like you said, it's another question. Good luck :D